# Webcrawling while bypassing 'important information page'

Tags: python, r, validation, web-scraping, web-crawler

I want to extract the fund price of the following link using `python` or `R`:

http://www.mpf.invesco.com.hk/html/en/mpf/prices.html

But every time I load the page in brower, it redirects me to the page below so to confirm that I have read the important information before I can gain access of the fund price.

http://www.mpf.invesco.com.hk/html/en/mpf/information.html

I guess that the 'important information page' is made by javascript. Can I use `R` or `python` to confirm that it has read the important information, and let it retrieve the fund price of the subsequent page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation is a bit simpler. The table you need is "sitting" inside the `iframe` that is loaded from [this url](https://apps.ap.invesco.com/invee/fund_info/fund_price_ns_mpf.do?version=en&haaccount=N&url=http://www.mpf.invesco.com.hk/html/pdf/factsheets/mpf).

Here's how you can get it using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and parse with [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'https://apps.ap.invesco.com/invee/fund_info/fund_price_ns_mpf.do?version=en&haaccount=N&url=http://www.mpf.invesco.com.hk/html/pdf/factsheets/mpf'
response = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
table = soup.find_all('table')[1]

# getting the first row for example
print table.tr.text.strip()
```

Prints:

```
Valuation Date: 10/07/2014
```

FYI, there is no need in `selenium` and real browser here.

Comment: How can you find that url? I have read the source of the page (http://www.mpf.invesco.com.hk/html/en/mpf/prices.html) but I cannot see it.

Comment: @lokheart I've just used browser developer tools, inspected network requests and the source of the page. Nothing magical here. Glad it helped.

Comment: I have another similar question asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341524/webcrawling-while-bypassing-important-information-page-2nd-scenario?lq=1 , wondering if you can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using `RSelenium` and `phantomjs`:

```
# use dev version so we can run phantomjs without a selenium server
# devtools::install_github("ropensci/RSelenium")
# it is necessary that phantomjs is in your PATH if not
# refer to package vignettes

library(RSelenium)
appURL <- "http://www.mpf.invesco.com.hk/html/en/mpf/prices.html"
pJS <- phantom()
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(appURL)
# <span onclick=\"accept();return false;\">I have read the Important Information</span>
# execute above code 
remDr$executeScript("accept();return false;")
# switch to iframe element
remDr$switchToFrame("myFrame")

> head(readHTMLTable(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
                     , which = 2, header = TRUE, skip.rows = 1))

Name of Constituent Fund Unit Class Currency
1                                                 Hong Kong and China Equity Fund          A      HKD
2                                                               Asian Equity Fund          A      HKD
3                                                                     Growth Fund          A      HKD
4                                                                   Balanced Fund          A      HKD
5 RMB Bond Fund (this Constituent Fund is denominated in HKD only and not in RMB)          A      HKD
6                                                             Capital Stable Fund          A      HKD
Fund Price
1    34.5537
2    10.2323
3    19.2199
4    18.8244
5     9.8299
6    18.3871
```

And finally close the `phantomjs` instance when done:

```
pJS$stop()
```